# Ethtool return "Operation not supported"

Tags: linux, mininet

I work in mininet and use ethtool to change configuration of switch but it return error and not work.
Can anyone know how to solve this?

```
$ sudo ethtool --pause s2-eth3 autoneg off rx off tx off
Cannot get device pause settings: Operation not supported

$ sudo ethtool --change s1-eth1 speed 1
Cannot set new settings: Operation not supported
  not setting speed
```

Comment: What switch are you using ? What's the output of dmesg | grep s2-eth3 ?

Comment: I use Ovsk switch. the output is 
[  309.094590] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): s2-eth3: link becomes ready
[  310.538704] device s2-eth3 entered promiscuous mode

Comment: Did you manage to solve it? If you did please share your solution :)

Comment: Until now i don't solve it.